# Laravel validation with unique fields

Tags: php, laravel

I have been trying unique validation in laravel 5.7. Below is my code for validation.

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|unique:permissions,name',
        'slug' => 'required|unique:permissions,slug', 
    ]);
```

And the html is below:

```
<div class='container'> 
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'permission.save','method'=>'POST')) !!}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <strong>Name:</strong>
            {!! Form::text('name', null, array('placeholder' => 'Name','class' => 'form-control')) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <strong>Slug:</strong>
            {!! Form::text('slug', null, array('placeholder' => 'Slug','class' => 'form-control')) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <strong>Description:</strong>
            {!! Form::textarea('description', null, array('placeholder' => 'Description','class' => 'form-control')) !!}
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

Unique validation for 'name' is working fine but it is not working for 'slug'. It's really weird i can't get it. Please provide suggestions to fix this issue. Any help would be great.

Comment: Code looks fine to me. What do you mean by “it’s not working”?

Comment: Provide html also.

Comment: @MartinBean unique is not working for 'slug'. But required is working. Its strang

Comment: can you please provide HTML that you are trying and error message as well?

Comment: @RamChander I have edited the post and added the html.

Comment: @WaqarAdil  I have edited the post and added the html.

Comment: @RamChander It is not throwing any error it just post my data.

Comment: in your table what is  column name for slug ?

Comment: @amitrawat please check if the column name ( for slug ) is set as unique

Comment: now please provide database structure

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify column name from database table in unique validation rule

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-unique

for example your column name for slug is : column_slug

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|unique:permissions,name',
    'slug' => 'required|unique:permissions,column_slug',   // column_slug  may be different in your case
]);
```

And ensure that you have set unique key for that column in database table

Hope it helps !